# Dynamically added form field doesn't post to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I add dynamically a field when a button is clicked, with this code:

```
jQuery("#yasr-add-field-edit-multiset").on('click', function() {
var newTextBoxDiv = jQuery(document.createElement('tr'))

newTextBoxDiv.html(' \
                    <td colspan="2">Element #' + counter + ' <input type="text" name="edit-multi-set-element-' + counter + ' " value="" > \
                    <input type="hidden" name="stored_field_id_for_row_' + counter + ' " value=" ' + counter + ' "></td> \
                  ');

newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#yasr-table-form-edit-multi-set");
```

This is the form and table that is showed

```
<form action=" <?php echo admin_url('options-general.php?page=yasr_settings_page') ?>" id="form_edit_multi_set" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="yasr_edit_multi_set_form" value="<?php echo $set_type ?>" />


        <table id="yasr-table-form-edit-multi-set">
            <tr>

                <td id="yasr-table-form-edit-multi-set-header"> 
                     //Code
                </td>

                 <td id="yasr-table-form-edit-multi-set-remove"> 
                    //code
                 </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

When I sand a value from the dynamically added input field, it's not send to the server, $_POST totally ignore it. I can't figure it out

Comment: OT: `jQuery(document.creatElement('tr'))` should just be `jQuery('<tr>')`.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with your code? It looks like it should work, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Is the browser inserting a TBODY element? If so, the inserted TR would come after that and be invalid.

Comment: Yes Jim, I didn't notice that: browser added tbody element, but the new tr it's attacched inside tbody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/H7B4x/4/) based on your code.

It adds the fields, but unfortunately jsFiddle blocks the `POST`ing `form`s. Therefore I can only use `$.serialize`to see what fields would be sent from the `form`.

According to my tests it `$.serialize` gathers all the necessary data, and the same should happen when `POST`ing the `form`.

#### Form

[image: form to submit]

Console output of `$.serialize`:

```
yasr_edit_multi_set_form=1&
edit-multi-set-element-0=hello&
stored_field_id_for_row_0=0&
edit-multi-set-element-1=world&
stored_field_id_for_row_1=1
```

My guess is that your issue lies somewhere else. Make sure you examine (Chrome dev tools / Firebug) the actual data that is posted, to see if they are sent from the browser or not.

If they are sent, your problem lies somewhere in the backend.

Comment: Interesting. It seems jQuery handles the case where you are appending to a table that has a tbody.